# Vercel cache CORS headers issue for multiple domains

Tags: caching, next.js, cors, vercel, http-status-code-304

I have a Next.js API deployed on Vercel.
The API is used by multiple other domains.

When the browser send the `If-None-Match` header, Vercel can reply with a 304; however, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header may contain a different origin, which causes a CORS error. I guess it's due to the fact Vercel sends the headers from the cached response.

How can I make sure the correct origin value will be specified in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?
I think I could add some proxy for every domains consuming the API but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, the problem is that Vercel doesn't include the request's origin in the cache key, and you get accidental [Web cache poisoning](https://portswigger.net/web-security/web-cache-poisoning). Unfortunately, Vercel [doesn't seem to allow custom cache keys](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/6141) yet.

A long-term solution would be to put pressure on Vercel for them to add the origin to the their cache key; this is a sensible default that other CDNs, such as Cloudflare, have adopted. An alternative, short-term solution would be to make your responses to CORS requests non-cacheable according to [Vercel caching rules](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/caching#cacheable-responses):

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/whatever",
      "headers": [
        { key: "Cache-Control", value: "no-cache" },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the reply.
For the moment I forced the client to not use `If-None-Match`. I'll ask Vercel support for that.
One thing that is weird is that there is an `authorization` header when the requests are made, so in theory Vercel should not cache them. Maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Weird indeed... Either there is another cache between Vercel and the client, or Vercel's documentation about its caching rules is incorrect.